# Two parameters in struts.xml

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am working on Struts2, I have an action, and I want to pass two parameters from that action, to a .JSP

I am doing this:

```
<action name="inscribirse" class="tdp.proyectoWeb.ManejadorJugadorAction" method="executeInsertarJugador"  > 
        <result name="success">Mensajes.jsp?m=JUGADOR CONFIRMADO</result>
        <result name="error">Mensajes.jsp?m=ERROR: NO SE PUEDE AGREGAR AL NUEVO JUGADOR</result>
</action>
```

See that I use ?m=Message to pass one parameter, but I want to pass two.
I tried this:

```
<result name="success">Mensajes.jsp?m=Message1&d=Message2</result>
```

But it didn't work

How can I solve this?

Comment: Yuck. Use `param` tag, or better set it in action.

Comment: What do you mean by "set it in action"? I tried <param name="p1">Message</param>, but it didn't work, I don't know why.

Comment: Inside your method just set `m` to something and use it in jsp. What is the issue?

Comment: It works if I only pass m, but I need to pass two parameters. And when I use <param> I can't use it un jsp, its null.

Comment: Use params in param tag via OGNL you won't mess that params.

Comment: Why are you trying to set it in struts.xml in the first place? See some tutorials: http://struts.apache.org/docs/tutorials.html.